# setting div to 100% view port size when page loads

Tags: css, html, layout

I am creating a website with divs as slides...

Somewhat of a parallax site.

I have the following HTML code

```
<div id='div1'>content</div>
<div id='div2'>content</div>
<div id='div3'>content</div>
<div id='div4'>content</div>
```

now I want the first div to talk up 100% height of the viewport.

the problem is that if I set the height:100% the page is fine at 90% zoom

but as soon as I zoom out and reload the page the div is not 100% the bottom div appears.

I short no matter the zoom of the browser the first div should have 100% of the viewing area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can tell that div... to be the height of the window, and call resize function with jquery... so what ever you resize it will keep the heihgt...

```
var hheight = $(window).height();
        $('#side_nav').css('height', hheight);
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var hheight = $(window).height();
            $('#side_nav').css('height', hheight);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `vh` if it works for you. `vh` & `vw` are viewport height and width.
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eKGSC/)**

```
<div class="sec sec1"></div>
<div class="sec sec2"></div>
<div class="sec sec3"></div>
<div class="sec sec4"></div>
```

---

```
.sec{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}
.sec1{
    background-color:red;
}
.sec2{
    background-color:blue;
}
.sec3{
    background-color:green;
}
.sec4{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```